# Docker Error : Cannot use --lxc-conf with execdriver: native-0.2

Tags: docker, ip, containers

My requirement is I want to provide Static IP for the container.

I use LXC-conf, [such as the following link](http://shellfu.com/2014/11/docker-assigning-static-ip-addresses-to-containers/) to set the IP DHCP / Static.

I've lakuakan namely

```
 docker run \
 --net="none" \ 
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.type = veth" \ 
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.23.38" \
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 192.168.23.1" \
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.link = dkr01" \
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.name = eth0" \
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.flags = up" \
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.veth.pair = sts" 
 -h sts \
 --name sts \
 -d ubuntu_erp:latest
```

When executing the last syntax, an error "Error response from daemon: Cannot use --lxc-conf with execdriver: native-0.2"

```
 docker run \
 --net="none" \ 
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.type = veth" \ 
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv4 = 192.168.23.38" \
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.ipv4.gateway = 192.168.23.1" \
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.link = dkr01" \
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.name = eth0" \
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.flags = up" \
 --lxc-conf="lxc.network.veth.pair = sts" 
 -h sts \
 --name sts \
 -d ubuntu_erp:latest
 Error response from daemon: Cannot use --lxc-conf with execdriver: native-0.2
```

I ask for help, for what I need.

Maybe of you who have a reliable docker, can help address my needs.
Want to give a DHCP IP according to the local intranet.